# Programmatically importing MS SAPI 5.1 Profiles

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition, sapi

I am trying to import MS speech profiles programatically using VB. What I am looking to do is basically perform all of the tasks of [SpProfileMgr](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22358) without using the interface. The overall goal is for us to pull a speech profile from our network so that it can be used on multiple computers. We already understand how to set a profile programatically using SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer, we just cannot pull that profile from the network without using the SpProfileMgr.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?  Can you load/set the profile programmatically from a local drive?  Or are you having problems reading the profile created by SpProfileMgr?